# How To Assign A USB Port To Virtual Com Port?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, modem

I have an ISDN modem with usb and com port and I want to plug it on my laptop with Windows 7 installed. I can't use this modem because my laptop doesn't have com port on it and I can't use it with the usb port because there are no drivers for windows 7 (there is a driver only for XP). This usb driver (for xp) virtualize the com port through usb port.

Is there a method to do this virtualization on Windows 7 (maybe using a existing application) ?

thanks

Comment: I edited your question a bit (still in the review-queue) to make it a bit more reader friendly. The specific model of the modem would help, maybe there is another sollution for your problem.